# Rewriting parts of a string

Tags: java, string

I have a string I would like to rewrite. The string contains substrings that look like "DDT" plus four digits. I'll call these blocks. It also contains connectives like "&" and "|", where | represents "or", as well as parentheses.

Now I would like to rewrite this string such that blocks separated by &s should be written as "min(x(block1), x(block2), etc.)", whereas blocks separated by |s should be written as "max(x(block1), x(block2), etc.)".

Looking at an example should help:

```
public class test{



 public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {


String str = "(DDT1453 & DDT1454) | (DDT3524 & DDT3523 & DDT3522 & DDT3520)";

System.out.println(str.replaceAll("DDT\\d+","x($0)"));

 }

}
```

My desired output is:

```
max(min(x(DDT1453),x(DDT1454)),min(x(DDT3524),x(DDT3523),x(DDT3522),x(DDT3520)))
```

As you can see, I performed an initial substitution to include the x(block) part of the output, but I cannot get the rest. Any ideas on how to achieve my desired output?

Comment: Beware of injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match your description.  Did you accidentally swap the `max` and `min` on the first two instances or is your description wrong?

Comment: A general outline of a solution: Write a recursive-descent parser for your input strings that generates a syntax tree. Walk that tree generating your desired output.

Comment: Use recursive descent to parse. The syntax is too rich for a straight regex approach.

Comment: Can you please send more correct (and incorrect) examples of input?  What should the program do in case of incorrect input?

Answer (score 0):

Just doing string substitution is the wrong way to go about this. Use Recursive-Descent Parsing instead

First you want to define what symbols create what for example:

> program -> LiteralArg|fn(x)|program
>
> LiteralArg -> LiteralArg
>
> LiteralArg&LiteralArg -> fn(LiteralArg) & fn'(LiteralArg)
>
> fn(x) -> fn(x)
>
> fn(x) |fn(y) -> fn(x),fn(y)

From there you make functions which will recursively parse your data expecting certain things to happen. For example

```
 String finalResult = "";
 function parse(baseString) {
     if(basestring.isLiteralArg)
     {
         if(peekAheadToCheckForAmpersand())
         {
              expectAnotherLiteralArgAfterAmpersandOtherwiseThrowError();
              finalResult += fn(LiteralArg) & fn'(LiteralArg)
              parse(baseString - recentToken);
         }
         else
         {
             finalResult += literalArg;
              parse(baseString - recentToken);
         }
     }
     else if(baseString.isFunction()
      {
           if(peekAheadToCheckForPipe())
           {
              expectAnotherFunctionAfterAmpersandOtherwiseThrowError();
                finalResult += fn(x),fn(y)
                 parse(baseString - recentToken);
           }
           else
           {
               finalResult += fn(x)
               parse(baseString - recentToken);
           }
      }

}
```

As you find tokens, take them off the string and call the parse function on the remaining string.

Rough example which I'm basing off a project I did years ago. Here is the relevant lecture:
http://faculty.ycp.edu/~dhovemey/fall2009/cs340/lecture/lecture7.html

Answer (score 0):

A full-blown parser for such a small grammar could be an overkill, specially when the OP obviously has no prior experience with them.  Not even using parser generators like ANTLR or JavaCC seems a good idea.

It's not easy to elaborate more with the current information.  OP, please provide information requested as comments to your question.

Tentative grammar:

```
maxExpr ::= maxExpr '|' '(' minExpr ')'
maxExpr ::= '(' minExpr ')'
minExpr ::= minExpr '&' ITEM
minExpr ::= ITEM
ITEM ::= 'DDT\d{4}'
```

Realized that, true, the grammar is excessive for a RegEx, but for a **single** RegEx.  Nobody is saying we can't use more than one.  In fact, even the simplest RegEx substitution can be regarded as a step in a Turing machine, and thus the problem is solvable using them.  So...

```
str= str.replaceAll("\\s+", "" ) ;
str= str.replaceAll("&", "," ) ;
str= str.replaceAll("\\([^)]+\\)", "-$0" ) ;
str= str.replaceAll("\\|", "," ) ;
str= str.replaceAll(".+", "+($0)" ) ;
str= str.replaceAll("\\w+", "x($0)" ) ;
str= str.replaceAll("\\+", "max" ) ;
str= str.replaceAll("-", "min" ) ;
```

I didn't take many shortcuts.  The general idea is that "+" equates to a production of `maxExpr` and "-" to one of `minExpr`.

I tested this with input

```
str= "(DDT1453 & DDT1454 & DDT1111) | (DDT3524 & DDT3523 & DDT3522 & DDT3520)" ;
```

Output is:

```
max(min(x(DDT1453),x(DDT1454),x(DDT1111)),min(x(DDT3524),x(DDT3523),x(DDT3522),x(DDT3520)))
```

Back to the idea of a grammar, it's easy to recognize that the significant elements of it really are  ITEMS  and  '|' .  All the rest (parentheses and '&') is just decoration.

Simplified grammar:

```
maxExpr ::= maxExpr '|' minExpr
maxExpr ::= minExpr
minExpr ::= minExpr ITEM
minExpr ::= ITEM
ITEM ::= 'DDT\d{4}'
```

From here, a very simple finite automaton:

```
<start>
    maxExpr= new List() ;
    minExpr= new List() ;

"Expecting ITEM" (BEFORE_ITEM):
    ITEM -> minExpr.add(ITEM) ; move to "Expecting ITEM, |, or END"

"Expecting ITEM, |, or END" (AFTER_ITEM):
    ITEM -> minExpr.add(ITEM) ; move to "Expecting ITEM, |, or END"
    | -> maxExpr.add(minExpr); minExpr= new List(); move to "Expecting ITEM"
    END -> maxExpr.add(minExpr); move to <finish>
```

... and the corresponding implementation:

```
static Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile("(\\()|(\\))|(\\&)|(\\|)|(\\w+)|(\\s+)") ;
static enum TokenType { OPEN, CLOSE, MIN, MAX, ITEM, SPACE, _END_, _ERROR_ };
static enum State { BEFORE_ITEM, AFTER_ITEM, END }

public static class Token {
    TokenType type;
    String value;
    public Token(TokenType type, String value) {
        this.type= type ;
        this.value= value ;
    }
}
public static class Lexer {
    Scanner scanner;
    public Lexer(String input) {
        this.scanner= new Scanner(input) ;
    }
    public Token getNext() {
        String tokenValue= scanner.findInLine(pattern) ;
        TokenType tokenType;
        if( tokenValue == null ) tokenType= TokenType._END_ ;
        else if( tokenValue.matches("\\s+") ) tokenType= TokenType.SPACE ;
        else if( "(".equals(tokenValue) ) tokenType= TokenType.OPEN ;
        else if( ")".equals(tokenValue) ) tokenType= TokenType.CLOSE ;
        else if( "&".equals(tokenValue) ) tokenType= TokenType.MIN ;
        else if( "|".equals(tokenValue) ) tokenType= TokenType.MAX ;
        else if( tokenValue.matches("\\w+") ) tokenType= TokenType.ITEM ;
        else tokenType= TokenType._ERROR_ ;
        return new Token(tokenType,tokenValue) ;
    }
    public void close() {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
public static String formatColl(String pre,Collection<?> coll,String sep,String post) {
    StringBuilder result= new StringBuilder() ;
    result.append(pre);
    boolean first= true ;
    for(Object item: coll ) {
        if( ! first ) result.append(sep);
        result.append(item);
        first= false ;
    }
    result.append(post);
    return result.toString() ;
}
public static void main(String... args) {

    String str= "(DDT1453 & DDT1454) | (DDT3524 & DDT3523 & DDT3522 & DDT3520)" ;
    Lexer lexer= new Lexer(str) ;
    State currentState= State.BEFORE_ITEM ;
    List<List<String>> maxExpr= new LinkedList<List<String>>() ;  
    List<String> minExpr= new LinkedList<String>() ;  
    while( currentState != State.END ) {
        Token token= lexer.getNext() ;
        switch( currentState ) {
        case BEFORE_ITEM:
            switch( token.type ) {
            case ITEM:
                minExpr.add("x("+token.value+")") ;
                currentState= State.AFTER_ITEM ;
                break;
            case _END_:
                maxExpr.add(minExpr) ;
                currentState= State.END ;
                break;
            default:
                // Ignore; preserve currentState, of course
                break;
            }
            break;
        case AFTER_ITEM:
            switch( token.type ) {
            case ITEM:
                minExpr.add("x("+token.value+")") ;
                currentState= State.AFTER_ITEM ;
                break;
            case MAX:
                maxExpr.add(minExpr) ;
                minExpr= new LinkedList<String>() ;
                currentState= State.BEFORE_ITEM ;
                break;
            case _END_:
                maxExpr.add(minExpr) ;
                currentState= State.END ;
                break;
            default:
                // Ignore; preserve currentState, of course
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    lexer.close();

    System.out.println(maxExpr);

    List<String> maxResult= new LinkedList<String>() ;
    for(List<String> minItem: maxExpr ) {
        maxResult.add( formatColl("min(",minExpr,",",")") ) ;
    }

    System.out.println( formatColl("max(",maxResult,",",")") );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using regex substitutions, then the following code seems to work:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\([^)]*\\)", "min$0");
str = str.replaceAll("DDT\\d+","x($0)");
str = str.replaceAll("&|\\|",",");
str = "max(" + str + ")";
```

**Hoewever**, I would consider what the others suggest - using a parsing logic instead.
This way you can extend your grammar easily in the future, and you'll also be able to validate the input and report meaningful error messages.

--EDIT--

The solution above assumes there's no nesting. If nesting is legal, then you definitely can't use the regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intested to learn and use ANTLR

Following ANTLR grammer

```
grammar DDT;

options {
  output       = AST;
  ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}

tokens {  DDT;  AMP;  PIPE;}

@members {}


expr  :  op1=amp (oper=PIPE^ op2=amp)*;
amp   :  op1=atom (oper=AMP^ op2=atom)*;
atom  :  DDT! INT   | '('! expr ')'!;

fragment

Digit  :  '0'..'9';
PIPE   :  '|'  ;
AMP    :  '&';
DDT    :  'DDT';
INT    :  Digit Digit*;
```

produces below AST (abstract syntax tree) for input `(DDT1 | DDT2) & (DDT3 | DDT4)  & DDT5`

[image: AST for DDT]

above syntax tree (`CommonTree`) could be walked in intended order (optionally using StringTemplates) and the desired result could be obtained.

Answer (score -1):

Regex is not the best choice to do this - or to say it right away: its not possible (in java).

Regex might be able to change the formating of a given String, using backreferenes, but it can not generate *content aware* backreferences. In other words: You would require some kind of recursion (or iterative solution) to resolve an infinite depth of nested parenthesis.

Therefore, you would need to write your own parser, that is able to handle your input.

While replacing the `DDT1234` Strings with the appropriate `x(DDT1234)` representation is easily doable (its a single backreference for ALL occurrences), you need to take care for correct nesting on your own.

For parsing nested expressions, you may want to have a look at this example:
**Parsing an Infix Expression with Parentheses (like ((2*4-6/3)*(3*5+8/4))-(2+3))**
http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html

Its just a (verbal) example of how to handle such a given string.